# sql server function to return concatenation of values faster than STUFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, proxy

How can I make a function that return a list of values separated by this `-` or `,`

I'm searching of a faster method that STUFF and FOR XML PATH, cause they make my db returning a 502 proxy for timeout.
is it possible?

my select is now:

```
stuff (( select ',' + column from table where  condition FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as result
```

25k records result's query - waiting time: 1 and a half minute

Other workarounds for that 502 proxy error are nice accepted

Comment: I think the `FOR XML PATH` + `STUFF` is the fastest there is.

Comment: Are you going to concatenate 25k values? Not really... Probably there is a 25k records table with some child data you want to concatenate for some kind of output... How many child records do you have per parent row?

Comment: the query is like 
select  column1,
stuff (...) as name
from table

and the result of this query is a 25k records table

Comment: Can you post the entire query?

Comment: Why are you sending 25,000 rows to the client? Are they really going to process 25,000 rows? Maybe you should consider pagination rather than magic grouped concatenation to solve your timeout issues...

Comment: I'm working with a cms, and it's like get all the data from the view, I could add only custom where conditions, but I dont thinks it's going to fast processing query time

Comment: About the only thing that might be faster is CLR or some other compiled app.